# iOS NSURLRequest in HTML form

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsurlrequest

I am creating a NSMutableURLRequest, a post request, so is there is a way I can check my request in HTML for so that i can verify with the web developer is my requests are proper or not.

Thank you.

Comment: so you want to check that request are generated or not right?

Comment: Request is generated or not that I can know by server response, but can i know my request structure which I am sending to server with the header and post data, authentication token etc .

Answer (score 2):

`NSURLRequest` and `NSMutableURLRequest` are Objective C objects which abstract away the raw bytes that are sent up to the server.

But you can approximate what the server sees by printing out (or using "`NSLog`") the contents of various properties of a `NSURLRequest` object.

For example:

```
- (void) printOutURLRequestInfo: (NSURLRequest *) yourRequest
{
    if(yourRequest)
    {
        NSLog( @"url is %@", [yourRequest.URL absoluteString]);
        NSLog( @"header fields (as a dictionary) is: %@", yourRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields );
        NSLog( @"request body is %@", yourRequest.HTTPBody);
        // and there are a number of other properties / pieces you can print 
        // out as well...
    } else {
        NSLog( @"why am I passing in a NULL NSURLRequest in here?");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that will certainly help